# JSP: Error in forwarding page

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

This question is related to the previous one, when I click over an anchor

```
<a href="#" id="Email">send email</a>
```

it calls servlet using json

```
   $("#Email").click(function() {

    var option={
        "action":"sendEmail"
    };
    $.getJSON('StudentManagementServlet',option, function(hasEmail) {
        if(hasEmail == false){
            // //view form to let user enter his email
            $("#CommViaEmail").fadeIn("normal");   
        }
    });
});
```

in servlet I handle the request

```
 if (action != null && action.equals("sendEmail")) {

    //open connection to db
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    String email = ParentManagement.getParentEmail(con, stdNo);
    if (email != null) {
        String commResult = createAccountAndSendEmail(con, parentNo, email);
        request.setAttribute("result", commResult);
        request.setAttribute("incp", "ResultPage");
         RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);  //doesn't make forward!!!!!
        System.out.println(">>send email DONE!!");
        con.commit();
        return;
    } else {
        boolean hasEmail = false;
        String json = new Gson().toJson(hasEmail);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);

    }
}
```

The problem here is if user has an email, then I send an email but request dosn't forward to result page, even the print statement is printed " System.out.println(">>send email DONE!!");" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let JS/jQuery do that job. Let the servlet write `true` as JSON result and in JS do

```
if (hasEmail) {
    window.location = 'index.jsp';
} else {
    $("#CommViaEmail").fadeIn("normal");   //view form to let user enter his email
}
```

Or when you want to control the URL yourself, add the new location to the JSON

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("hasEmail", true);
data.put("location", "index.jsp");
// ...
```

with

```
..., function(data) {
    if (data.hasEmail) {
        window.location = data.location;
    } else {
        $("#CommViaEmail").fadeIn("normal");   //view form to let user enter his email
    }
}
```

Comment: @BalusC, I have many attributes to forward with the request, how can I forward them using javascript?

Comment: You could pass them as request parameters instead. After all, why would you like to forward to another page? Why not just show some success message straight in the same page?

Comment: @BalusC, my teacher told me once that in web applications, results r shown in another page.

Comment: @BalusC, how can I pass them as request parameters??

Comment: 1) That's how they did in 90's, yes. 2) by adding them as request parameters to the URL. E.g. `index.jsp?foo=bar&waa=moo`.

Comment: @balusC,  in the question I show only 2 parameters, but they r five, I don't think it's a good solution :S

Answer (score 0):

You are making an AJAX request from the client and are trying to 'forward' that request in the server side.

AJAX requests **DONT** refresh the page. The `hasEmail` variable in **javascript function** will be a string containing the HTML of the `index.jsp`.

Comment: hasEmail variable has boolean variable not string, this variable let me know that user doesn't have an email, so I show his a from to add his email.

Comment: It will be false only if the "else" block in your server side code gets executed. Otherwise, it will contain a string of html from index.jsp.

Comment: I can't find where I set the index.jsp to hasEmail variable!

Comment: I am referring to the hasEmail variable in javascript function. http://docs.jquery.com/GetJSON the argument to the callback function contains the response from the server. In your Javascript code that happens to be hasEmail. So if the 'if' block gets executed in server side, 'hasEmail' in JS will have the HTML string of JSP. If the 'else' block gets executed, it will be a JSON object evaluating to false. Hope this makes sense.